# XCode 7.0 Non-binary files being treated as embedded binary files

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

Since XCode 4 I have been including some files in my build that contain reference to what I call content in the application.  In the application bundle they are included in a content.bundle directory with a directory name of {UUID}.bundle.

While I know from Apple's and XCode's perspective, this naming convention might be confusing and unfortunate due to Apple's special .bundle folder type, up until now, I have had no issue and the app even exists in the app store.

Now with XCode 7, there appears to be an issue and I see no setting to disable it.

I am receiving the following errors:

```
ValidateEmbeddedBinary /tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/content.bundle/4bf8dec0-6da8-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66.bundle
    cd /Users/jonl/Code/SRTS_IOS_Workspace/SRTS_IOS_Client
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility /tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/content.bundle/4bf8dec0-6da8-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66.bundle -signing-cert 215CA47B084DE3D34C29926F510BE03D024EE72C -info-plist-path /tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/Info.plist
error: Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fed63cd5460:'/tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/content.bundle/4bf8dec0-6da8-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66.bundle'>

ValidateEmbeddedBinary /tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/content.bundle/857a61e0-5800-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66.bundle
    cd /Users/jonl/Code/SRTS_IOS_Workspace/SRTS_IOS_Client
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility /tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/content.bundle/857a61e0-5800-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66.bundle -signing-cert 215CA47B084DE3D34C29926F510BE03D024EE72C -info-plist-path /tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/Info.plist
error: Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fed63cf3f10:'/tmp/SRTS/Products/SRTS.app/content.bundle/857a61e0-5800-11e1-b86c-0800200c9a66.bundle'>
```

I have attempted to rename the directories to something besides ending in a ".bundle" suffix, but that has not had a change either.

Is anyone aware of a setting that has changed that would cause this or some setting that I could add to exclude these files from being passed to the ValidateEmbeddedBinary mechanism?

I have also reported this as a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this shortly after posting the question.  There was a bug in the manner in which XCode 7 was handling the bundles.  After the next update to XCode, removing and readding the files from XCode caused it to use the files correctly and this is no longer an issue.